# Tangent Plane to sphere using 3D

Tags: 3d

How to find the tangent plane to sphere say, $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} +2ux+2vy+2wz+d=0$ from the point $P(x1,y1,z1)$ not necessarily on the sphere.

If possible, solve using 3D not vectors.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote ?

Comment: Link it to "What has been so far done?"

Comment: I tried calculating for a given sphere and point. First finding the intersection point of plane and sphere (Assuming l,m,n as direction cosines). Also finding one more equation by making perpendicular distance equal to radius. But it did not seem to be the right approach as l,m,n could not be easily solved from it.

Comment: Solutions on the web used partial derivatives and vectors, which I am not allowed to use right now!

Comment: You cannot  use vectors, why?

Comment: The topic is not in my syllabus.

Comment: There is a problem; there is an infinite number of planes issued from a given point and tangent to the sphere....

Comment: Really ? How ? Shouldn't there be max 2 such planes.

Comment: You have a point,you have the centre of the sphere, thus you have a vector which is perpendicular to the plane and (from above) a point on the plane thus you can describe the plane.

Comment: About the fact there are an infinite number of planes  tangent to a sphere S and passing through an exterior point P : do you agree with me that from P one can draw tangent lines to S that generate a cone. Along each of these lines L, one can draw a tangent plane to the cone which is as well a tangent plane to the sphere ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: You can calculate a second point, which would satisfy the equation of a plane. Find the second point by using the vectors: $\mathbf{x}',\mathbf{y'}, \mathbf{z'}$. 
$$\mathbf{x}'=\dfrac{\mathbf{x}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^2+\mathbf{y}^2+\mathbf{z}^2}}, \mathbf{y}'=\dfrac{\mathbf{y}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^2+\mathbf{y}^2+\mathbf{z}^2}}, \mathbf{z}'=\dfrac{\mathbf{z}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^2+\mathbf{y}^2+\mathbf{z}^2}}$$

Each of this vectors should satisfy the following equation:

$$(x_1+u)^2+(y_1+v)^2+(z_1+w)^2-[\mathbf{x'}(x_1+u)+\mathbf{y'}(y_1+v)+\mathbf{z'}(z_1+w)]^2=r^2$$

Applying this to the sphere $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} +2ux+2vy+2wz+d=0$ gives:
$$x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2+2x_1u+2y_1v+2z_1w+d-[\mathbf{x'}(x_1+u)+\mathbf{y'}(y_1+v)+\mathbf{z'}(z_1+w)]^2=0$$